# Regular Expression How to match a word which end with certain character but not select the last character?

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture the word which ends with [u] but not selecting the last character. 
The example of my target result is:

**Target result**

```
Original Word -> Capture Group-> Select Only
Grāveru pagasts -> Grāveru -> Grāver
Balvu novads -> Balvu -> Balv
```

**My current approach**

`(.*)(?<=u)\spagasts  which will capture Grāveru
(.*)(?<=u)\snovads which will capture Balvu`

[image]

My target result is the word without last character (Grāver) but I am stuck at this stage, Do anyone has any idea?

Comment: Is this some kind of [Lemmatisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation)? If it is, you should use proper tools to do so. Regex will only give you head aches down the road.

Comment: yeap, I am doing some Lemmatisation in address analysis. Which kind of tools would you suggest?

Comment: I would use the [Apache Opennlp](https://opennlp.apache.org/) for start. It has a good lemmatizer and also a stemmer combining both will give you a much better result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use positive lookahead.

```
\p{L}+(?=u\b)
```

or

```
\S+(?=u\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zPgrCe/1)

Comment: Your code is great but it will break when "Mālupes pagasts".

Comment: Sorry my fault, it won't get match. Your answer is correct.

Comment: Why your regrex won't match the foo in  ```foo Grāveru pagasts``` ?   I couldn't get it.

Comment: @YoongKangLim op wants to match a single word not the whole sentence (all the chars before u including whitespaces)

Comment: The ```.```  in ```.*``` will match all the chars including white space. So it will select all whole sentence, I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
(.+)(?=[u]\b)
```

`(?<=[u])`: look behind,
`(?=[u])`: Lookahead

`\b` to match word end

EDIT:
if only need match words, should update to: `(\S+)(?=[u]\b)`

Comment: Your answer is great but your regrex will match everything even when U is in the middle 
Example: Mālupes will match Mālu

Comment: @YoongKangLim, how about this one?

Comment: this should match also the `foo` text in `foo Grāveru pagasts` and also I don't think a char class is necessary here.